# Retrieving an Amazon Store's List of products using PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

*My apologies if this is a duplicate question, but I haven't come across anything that is of much help.*

I am building a website for a client that is an index of their eBay and Amazon stores. This requires building a list of products that are currently in each. The eBay API has a GetSellerItems call that is simple enough, but I am having a harder time finding something similar in Amazon's AWS.

I've looked at the Product Advertising API briefly, but I am not convinced this is what I need.

**Basically, how do I retrieve a list of a specific Amazon store's products with PHP?**

Thanks for any leads or tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was best able to get the inventory of my store by registering with Amazon Marketplace Web Services (https://developer.amazonservices.com/) and using the reports API.

Comment: can you explain how to get all product list, while i submit requetreport (_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_ALL_DATA_) , i got only the request report id, how to fetch the details using that id

Answer (score 1):

http://aws.amazon.com/code/Product-Advertising-API/4373 I think this is one of the most popular one's

There are also other php based libraries available at..

http://aws.amazon.com/code/Product%20Advertising%20API?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1