# retrieve a list of products from my store on amazon

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I want to retrieve a list of my products on sale in my store on amazon. What I did was open the Amazon MWS scratchpad and selected feeds then getFeedSubmissions and entered the seller id, AWSAccessKeyId, and secret key. After I press submit this is the result that gets returned:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetFeedSubmissionListResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-01-01/">
<GetFeedSubmissionListResult>
  <NextToken/>
  <HasNext>false</HasNext>
  <FeedSubmissionInfo>
    <FeedSubmissionId>########</FeedSubmissionId>
    <FeedType>_CHECKSUM_CLEARING_FEED_</FeedType>
    <SubmittedDate>2013-11-22T08:59:07+00:00</SubmittedDate>
    <FeedProcessingStatus>_DONE_</FeedProcessingStatus>
    <StartedProcessingDate>2013-11-22T08:59:43+00:00</StartedProcessingDate>
    <CompletedProcessingDate>2013-11-22T09:00:16+00:00</CompletedProcessingDate>
  </FeedSubmissionInfo>
</GetFeedSubmissionListResult>
<ResponseMetadata>
  <RequestId>xxxxxxxx</RequestId>
</ResponseMetadata>
</GetFeedSubmissionListResponse>
```

I read somewhere in another post where someone mentioned to use the Reports api and I tried that and I still didn't retrieve a list of products in my store. What am I doing wrong? I tried reading the api docs and their useless.

this is the post I read, I tried it and nothing... [Retrieving an Amazon Store's List of products using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589556/retrieving-an-amazon-stores-list-of-products-using-php)

Comment: Nothing as in empty response?

Comment: nothing as in the response i get, as shown above.

Comment: Show how you are posting the data, AWS is very strict on the order with which the parameters are sent to the server

Comment: i just went here, https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html and selected feed then getFeedSelection and entered my auth info then pressed submit. and thats the result i got above.

Comment: So something is off with your seller ID/ AWS Access ID/ Secret Key or their combination. You sure your Seller ID is the one with the items in it?

Comment: yes the seller id is correct, the other information is correct is as well. where was the page that lets me double check? or create a new one?

Comment: found it, https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#security_credential

Comment: i created new ones and now it says access denied :/ starting to want to give up...

Comment: Can't help you with giving up